# Grabbing an element of an array

Tags: javascript, if-statement, foreach

```
var input = prompt();
var binput = input.split("");
var inputl = input.split(" ").length

if ( inputl % 5 == 0 ) {
    binput.forEach(function(v, i) {
        if (v === "a") {
            binput[i] = "$"
        }
    })
}
```

My problem here is that I want only the 5th 10th 15th... element of `inputl` to be changed and now it changes the whole text `if (inputl % 5 == 0)`. However I only want to grab the fifth element of `inputl`'s array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my problem here is that i want only the 5th 10th 15th

try this

```
binput.forEach(function(v, i) { //iterate once
     if( (i + 1 ) % 5 == 0)  //check if the element is 5th, 10th, 15th etc
     {
         binput[i] = "$"; //assign the value as you like
     }
}};
```

**Edit:**

If you also want to check if the value is 'a' before assigning it new value, then try

```
binput.forEach(function(v, i) { //iterate once
     if( v == "a" && ( (i + 1 ) % 5 == 0 ) )  //check if the element is 5th, 10th, 15th etc
     {
         binput[i] = "$"; //assign the value as you like
     }
}};
```

Comment: i think you messed up something i cant get it working, the idea is really good tho

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( inputl % 5 == 0 ){    
  binput.forEach(function(v, i) {  
     if( (i + 1 ) % 5 == 0) {    
        if(v === "a") {    
  binput[i] = "$"    
}}    
})}
```

i got it working with this thank you for your time